# Display 2 fields in a cell in SonataAdminBundle

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin

I cannot find the answer to this anywhere on the web. How do I configure the `ListMapper` in `SonataAdminBundle` to show 2 fields in one cell?

I have an entity User with fields `firstname` and `lastname`. This code displayes them in separate cell

```
$listMapper
->addIdentifier('firstname')
->add('lastname')
->add('enabled');
```

How can I configure it to show both `firstname` and `lastname` in same cell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One hacky solution is to add a method to your entity (or its variation):

```
public function getFullName() { 
    return $this->getFirstName() . ' ' . $this->getLastName(); 
}
```

and then use:

```
->add('fullName')
```